# Whenever Charles is shut down, the macOS Proxy auto turned on. How to fix that?

Tags: charles-proxy

I use Charles. Sometimes needing the macOS Proxy on, but sometimes OFF.

When my macOS Proxy on, my browser cannot be used. So I need to turn it OFF.

[image]

However, lately, even after turning it OFF, when I shut down Charles, my browser internet not working again. I need to launch Charles, and found out that macOS Proxy is ON by itself. I have to explicitly turn it OFF and keep Charles running in order to use my browser internet.

How can I fix this issue (i.e. I want to shut down Charles and have the macOS Proxy OFF as well)?

Answer (score 5):

Try doing Proxy > Proxy settings > MacOS and uncheck "Enable MacOS proxy on launch"